# Is NSOperation available on iOS sdk 3.2?

Tags: ios, ipad, nsoperation

I'm developing an app that needs a real boost from multi-threading features like NSOperation provides. I'm worried about not being able to provide my app to the iOS 3.2 user base. So my question is basically that. Is NSOperation available on iOS sdk 3.2? If not, is it possible to make it available by linking the library?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I believe it is.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Availability
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.